# Is the total index of fixed points conserved before and after a bifurcation?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

A simple example I considered is three identical un-coupled ODEs

$\dot{x}_j = r x_j - x^3_j, \quad r,x_j \in \mathbb{R}, \quad j = 1,2,3.$

When $r>0$, there are multiple fixed points with different indices in the state space $\mathbb{R}^3$. If I define an index of a fixed point as

$I = (-1)^{N_r}$

where $N_r$ is the number of repelling eigen-directions of that fixed point, then in this case they are: One unstable node (+1), eight stable nodes (+8), and eighteen saddle points (6-12=-6). So the total index is +3.

However, when $r\le 0$, through pitch-fork bifurcations, there is only one stable node at the origin $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (0,0,0)$, which has index +1.

Should the total index be conserved through a bifurcation? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how you're computing $N_r$. Is this the number of strictly positive eigenvalues the Jacobian has at each equilibrium point? Why would the origin not have an index of $-1$ for $r > 0$, considering that Jacobian has the eigenvalue $r$ with a multiplicity of $3$ at the origin?

Comment: @MichaelLee Fixing this miscalculation should answer the question :)

Comment: Thanks! I miscalculated the index of the origin when $r>0$ …